# Web Scraping drop down menu with tag button and with no options

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I can't get the data from diferents options inside of drop down button in this page https://www.sofascore.com/team/football/palmeiras/1963.

The button that i have to change the option to get the diferents data is located with the following xpath: `//*[@id="downshift-5-toggle-button"]/div/span/span`

The data that i want to scrape is located right bellow that button, within five cards, with informations like Matches, Goals scored, Assists...

I figured out how to import the data from the cards that i need, but i can only import from the first option of the drop down button that is already selected with the initial loading of the site.

Comment: Open Chrome DevTools (`Ctrl+Shift+J`) > Networks. Click `Fetch/XHR` & `circle with "/"` icon. Change the `"button"` input manually, and API reqs will appear. Investigate and access the appropriate ones with `requests.get(url).json()`. E.g. get `id` per season from `url = 'https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/unique-tournament/325/seasons'`. So, `2021` would be `'.../v1/team/1963/unique-tournament/325/season/36166/top-players/overall'`. For the ratings, you can use: `requests.get(url).json()['topPlayers']['rating']`. I think `<= 2015`, the json data changes shape, so you'll have to manage that.

Comment: Hey ouroboros1, i did this way, but got my IP banned from the site just after did it for the first time :(. But, at least once, it worked! Thanks for that anyway. Do you know how to do this import without using their API? I wish i could do that doing web scraping.